# Button not taking css attributes

Tags: css

So I have a `button` inside a `div`. I want to make the `font-weight: bold` so I put it in the css. I fire up the website and the text of the button isn't *bold*. I then check it with Firebug and the `font-weight: bold` isn't even there? When I manually type it there in firebug my text becomes *bold*, just as I want it.

I'm working with bootstrap, here is the css of the button:

```
.btn-primary {
   background: url("../img/bg-nav.png") repeat-x scroll left bottom #198901;
   color: #ffffff;
   font: 17px "bowlby_oneregular",sans-serif !important;
   font-weight: bold;
   text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

I find it strange that it doesn't show up with Firebug, and yet when I put it there with Firebug it works

Comment: It works if you split `font` into `font-size` and `font-family` or if you remove `!important`.

Comment: It does work on Chrome and Firefox. http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/gcnwcf7e/

Comment: @Xufox that was it thank you! Is there any way I can mark it as the answer to my problem?

Comment: @user3142255 Now you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two solutions:

Remove `!important`:

```css
font:17px "bowlby_oneregular",sans-serif;
font-weight:bold;
```

Split the shorthand property up:

```css
font-size:17px;
font-family:"bowlby_oneregular",sans-serif;
font-weight:bold;
```

The exact solution depends on how exactly you want to apply the fonts. But I’d simply rewrite your code so that `!important` will never become necessary.